# Error with win32event.OpenEvent when trying to get a handle to a named Windows event

Tags: python, windows, events, service, pywin32

I've created a Windows service in Python that will launch my main application (an executable built in Python) after some inactivity timeout. That service uses `win32event` to set up a synchronization event for communication between itself and my main application. The event named `'EXIT_EVENT'` is created when the service is started, and is ultimately signaled by my main application when it exits so as to tell the service "hey the main app isn't open any more, restart the inactivity timer."

When I run my service in debug mode via the `ServiceFramework` CLI using `py helperservice.py debug`, everything works as expected.

But when I use Services.msc to "Start" the service normally, my main app throws an exception while trying to access the synchronization event.

```
# helperservice.py
import win32event

exit_event = win32event.CreateEvent(
    None,  # no security flags
    True,  # make this a resettable event
    False,  # initialize to False
    'EXIT_EVENT'  # name
)
```

```
# app.py
import win32event

try:
    exit_event_hdl = win32event.OpenEvent(
        win32event.EVENT_ALL_ACCESS,  # permissions
        True,  # bInheritHandle flag (not sure I need this)
        'EXIT_EVENT',
    )
except win32event.error as err:
    print(err)
```

When my application tries to access the named event as shown, it fails with the following error:

```
pywintypes.error: (2, 'OpenEvent', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

I expect this error to occur if the service isn't running when the main app is started, but the service is *definitely* started before the main app in this case.

It's as if the named event isn't created when running the service "normally", but it *is* created when running in `debug` mode. Why is this event interaction broken by the normal use case? As far as I can tell, the issue lies in the call to `OpenEvent`, because I've verified that the call to `CreateEvent` is returning a `PyHANDLE` object as expected.

Any insight / information is much appreciated, as ever.

---

***Additional Info That Might Be Relevant:***

My main application is built as a single-file executable via pyinstaller, and the service opens it after an inactivity timeout by calling `subprocess.Popen('<path>/<to>/app.exe')`. This part is working - the application is launched, but fails with the exception above shortly thereafter.

---

***EDIT:***

<strike>This appears to be a permissions error masquerading as a file error! When running in debug mode via the CLI, I'm running an admin prompt. But my application itself is running with general privileges! I just tried running `py helperservice.py debug` from a non-elevated prompt and got the same error, plus a much more useful `pywintypes.error: (5, 'RegOpenKeyEx', 'Access is denied.')` error.</strike>

I suppose now the question is: **how, if at all possible, can I signal from my app to my service without the app running with elevated privileges** (which I can't do - it's a requirement for this app to be run under general user accounts).

Further testing has revealed that...this ain't it, chief. I just tried running my application as Administrator and I'm *still* getting the same exception when it starts up.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: A quick read of the Win32 help for CreateEvent ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa ), and the link to SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, says: "If lpEventAttributes is NULL, the event gets a default security descriptor. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for an event come from the primary or impersonation token of the creator." A default security descriptor is not the same as having no access restrictions.

Comment: @DS_London Yeah, I did go down that particular rabbit hole a bit yesterday! But I ended up settling for just modifying my service loop to poll if my application was running or not...it ended up being easier to implement and fit the need since all I care about is essentially "is this running or not". Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Is this solved? I'm just solving (or trying to) all of your open questions. It's my new MO for answering questions. Put my effort into people that aren't brand new.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy technically no, but I ended up going a different route anyway, so this question is sort of moot at this point. Thanks though!